# How to deploy just a subfolder to Railway App

Tags: laravel, railway

I am using Railway to deploy my backend app's. I am currently working with a monorepo so I have a ui/ folder and a api/ folder, which contains my laravel application.

I know that it exists the subfolder root option in railway. However, I'd like to know how I could upload just the api/ folder instead of the whole project, which makes no sense to me...

Thanks !

I tried with "railway run cd api/ && php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --force" but the commands take those 2 sub-commands as different so actually, it "cd" to api/ but then, when running the php artisan command, it says it is placed at / instead of api/